# Is it possible to set color for the user input in bashrc?

Tags: colors, bashrc, .bash-profile

Note that I only want user's input to have specific color (words that user has typed with keyboard), not the actual command's output.

I tried:

```
export PS1="$ \033[38;5;154m"
```

I know that it should be closed with `\033[m` but I have no clue how to insert it *after* the input was sent to stdin.

```
export PS1="$ \033[38;5;154m$PS1\033[m"
```

This doesn't work either.

The reason why I want this is to be able to easily distinguish the input command from it's output. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash won't be able to color all user input.  UNIX is full-duplex and all data displayed comes from the unix machine, not from the local terminal emulator/keyboard so the terminal emulator (xterm?) can't really tell the difference, and bash only controls what it does, not what every program does.

I use a different colored prompt.

```
e=$'\e'
COLORblue="$e[0;34m"
COLORred="$e[0;31m"
COLORreset="$e[0m"
PC="$COLORblue"
if [[ "$EUID" -eq 0 ]]; then PC="$COLORred"; fi
PS1="\[$PC\]#===> \@ %\j / \u @ \h : \w/\n#===> \\\$ \[$COLORreset\]"

# Print when exit status is not 0 -- I like this too... shown in red
export PROMPT_COMMAND="x0=\$?;if ((\$x0 > 0)); then echo '${COLORred}# exit status = '\$x0' -- From PROMPT_COMMAND$COLORreset'; fi"
```

Maybe check

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841143/how-to-set-font-color-for-stdout-and-stderr

Answer (score 3):

I've been working on this and a few other bash/terminal things all day, and figured I'd find any relevant questions and answer them if I could even be of any remote help -- so the below .bashrc will color the terminmal input command green and the output will be standard white. The background is still black.

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.

# Created by EDH automated script to set up terminal colors
# Ref: http://linux.die.net/man/1/echo
# Ref: https://www.kirsle.net/wizards/ps1.html#help
# Ref: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Color_Bash_Prompt
# Ref: http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash

# Note: reload settings w/o relogin; source ~/.bashrc

# for terminal line coloring
export PS1="\[$(tput sgr0)\]\[$(tput setaf 1)\]\u \[$(tput setaf 6)\]\w \[$(tput setaf 1)\]\\$ \[$(tput setaf 2)\]"
none="$(tput sgr0)"
trap 'echo -ne "${none}"' DEBUG

# ls dir coloring
export LS_OPTIONS='--color=auto'
eval "`dircolors`"
alias ls='ls $LS_OPTIONS'
alias ll='ls $LS_OPTIONS -l'
alias l='ls $LS_OPTIONS -lA'
```

I tried to include the sources where I found them! Hope this helps, even if this is an older thread.

Answer (score 1):

I don't *think* you can get a different color for input commands and their output. In any case, you certainly cannot do this by setting the `PS1` variable. The `PS1` is the prompt, the text displayed to the left of whatever you type in. For example:

[image]

You can change the default colors of the terminal by modifying your `.Xdefaults` and/or `.Xresources` file. Have a look [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/X_resources#Terminal_colors), [here](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/katz/unix-colors.html) and [here](http://crunchbang.org/forums/viewtopic.php?id=9935) for some more information.